# How to run a program forever in Java? Is System.in.read() the only way?

Tags: java

I took [this code](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/getting-started.html#d4e54):

```
 28     public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
 29         HttpServer httpServer = startServer();
 30         System.out.println(String.format("Jersey app started with WADL available at "
 31                 + "%sapplication.wadl\nTry out %shelloworld\nHit enter to stop it...",
 32                 BASE_URI, BASE_URI));
 33         System.in.read();
 34         httpServer.stop();
 35     }
```

Does line 33 "System.in.read()" means that it will block until there is input? Will this also work when starting the Java application using UNIX rc script - not manually started from a command line?

I'd like to write a Java application to listen for HTTP connections. The application will be started automatically when the system boots (using UNIX rc scripts). It means that the application will run continuously - theoretically forever, until purposefully stopped. What is the best way to implement this in the Java main() method?

Comment: Don't stop the `httpService` ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Leaving the `main` method in Java does *not* automatically end the program.

The JVM exists if no more non-daemon threads are running. By default the only non-daemon thread is the main thread and it ends when you leave the `main` method, therefore stopping the JVM.

So *either* don't end the main thread (by not letting the `main` method return) *or* create a new non-daemon thread that never returns (at least not until you *want* the JVM to end).

Since that rule is actually quite sensible there is *usually* a perfect candidate for such a thread. For a HTTP server, for example that could be the thread that actually accepts connections and hands them off to other threads for further processing. As long as that code is running, the JVM will continue running, even if the `main` method has long since finished running.

Comment: You're not answering the question fully IMHO. You're not saying how to block the non-daemon thread. As I posted bellow http://stackoverflow.com/a/33502519/3114959 very elegant way to do so is to call `Thread.currentThread().join();`.

Comment: Purposefully blocking on the main thread without it having any actual work to do is the wrong approach. It's better to mark the thread that does actual work as a non-daemon thread. If you have no such thread, then the question is why you need a running JVM ;-)

Answer (score 47):

It looks like a weird black magic but following does the trick in very elegant way

```
Thread.currentThread().join();
```

As a result the current thread, `main` for instance, waits on `join()` for thread `main`, that is itself, to end. Deadlocked.

The blocked thread must not be a daemon thread of course.

Comment: this worked perfect. not sure if there is any other problem

Answer (score 7):

@Joachim's answer is correct.

But if (for some reason) you still want to block the main method indefinitely (without polling), then you can do this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Set up ...
    try {
        Object lock = new Object();
        synchronized (lock) {
            while (true) {
                lock.wait();
            }
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
    }
    // Do something after we were interrupted ...
}
```

Since the lock object is only visible to this method, nothing can `notify` it, so the `wait()` call won't return.  However, some other thread could still unblock the `main` thread ... by interrupting it.

Comment: Theoretically `wait` could wake up spuriously (without a corresponding `notify()` call). That's why you should never call it outside a loop.

Answer (score 1):

`while (true) { ... }` should go on for a pretty long time. Of course, you'll have to figure out some way of stopping it eventually.

A common trick is to have some `volatile boolean running = true`, then have the main loop be `while (running) { ... }` and define some criteria by which a thread sets `running = false`.

Comment: I thought about using a "while(true);" loop as well, but will the thread running this be evaluating the expression continuously, thereby consuming unnecessary CPU cycles?

Comment: Well, it depends on what it's doing. If it spends most of its time waiting for data from an HTTP connection, then it won't be consuming unnecessary CPU cycles. I should have clarified that I wasn't suggesting an empty loop (known as busy waiting), but rather a main event loop.

Answer (score 1):

Back to Threads, thats exactly what i wanted. Btw this awesome [tutorial](http://pirate.shu.edu/~wachsmut/Teaching/CSAS2214/Virtual/Lectures/chat-client-server.html) helped me a lot.

Main.java

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ChatServer server = null;
        /*if (args.length != 1)
            System.out.println("Usage: java ChatServer port");
        else*/
            server = new ChatServer(Integer.parseInt("8084"));
    }
}
```

and ChatServer.java Class extends a Runnable

```
public class ChatServer implements Runnable
{  private ChatServerThread clients[] = new ChatServerThread[50];
    private ServerSocket server = null;
    private Thread       thread = null;
    private int clientCount = 0;

    public ChatServer(int port)
    {  try
    {  System.out.println("Binding to port " + port + ", please wait  ...");
        server = new ServerSocket(port);
        System.out.println("Server started: " + server);
        start(); }
    catch(IOException ioe)
    {
        System.out.println("Can not bind to port " + port + ": " + ioe.getMessage()); }
    }

    public void start() {  
        if (thread == null) {  
            thread = new Thread(this);
            thread.start();
        }
    }
.... pleas continue with the tutorial
```

So in the main Method a Runnable is being instantiated and a new Thread as shown in
`public void start() {`
is being instantiated with the runnable.
That cases the JVM to continue executing the process until you quit the project or the debugger.

Btw thats the same as Joachim Sauer posted in his answere.

Answer (score 1):

Java program terminates when there are no non-daemon threads running. All you need is to have one such running thread. You could do it using infinite loops but that would consume CPU cycles. The following seems like a reasonable way to do it.

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
executor.submit(() -> {}); //submit a task that does what you want (in this case, nothing)
```

Answer (score -1):

Also we can achieve the same with the ReentrantLock and call wait() on it:

```
public class Test{
private static Lock mainThreadLock = new ReentrantLock();

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

System.out.println("Stop me if you can");
synchronized (mainThreadLock) {
    mainThreadLock.wait();
 }
}
```