# Is there anyway to write small file into S3 as live streaming

Tags: java, multithreading, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am getting 20k small xml files 1kb to 3kb size in a minute.
I have to write all the files as it arrives in the directory.

Sometimes the speed of the incoming files increases to 100k per minute.
Is there anything in java or aws api that can help me match the incoming speed?

I am using `uploadFileList()` API to upload all the files .
I have tried watch event as well so that when ever files arrives in a folder it will upload that file into S3 but that is so slow compared to incoming files and creates huge amount of backlogs.

I have tried multi threading also but if i spin up more thread i get error from S3 `reduce you request rate error.`
and some times i get below error also

> AmazonServiceException:
>   com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Your socket
>   connection to the server was not read from or written to within the
>   timeout period. Idle connections will be closed.

but when i dot use threading i do not get this error

Another way I also have tried is to create one big files and then upload into S3 and then in S3 i again split it into small files which is fine but this solution delays the files upload int S3 and impacts the user who access this file from S3.

I know uploading small files into S3 is not suitable but i have use case like that.

The speed i noticed is 5k files upload in a minutes.

Can someone please suggest some alternate way so that my speed of uploading files will increase least 15k per minutes.

I am sharing my full code where i am trying to upload using multi threaded application

Class one where i create File to put into thread

```
public class FileProcessThreads {

    public  ArrayList process(String fileLocation)  {

        File dir = new File(fileLocation);
        File[] directoryListing = dir.listFiles();
        ArrayList<File> files = new ArrayList<File>();
        if (directoryListing.length > 0) {
            for (File path : directoryListing) {
                files.add(path);
            }
        }
        return files;
    }
}
```

Class 2 where i create Thread pool and Executor

```
public class UploadExecutor {
private static String fileLocation = "C:\\Users\\u6034690\\Desktop\\ONEFILE";
// private static String fileLocation="D:\\TRFAudits_Moved\\";
private static final String _logFileName = "s3FileUploader.log";
private static Logger _logger = Logger.getLogger(UploadExecutor.class);

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static void main(String[] args) {
    _logger.info("----------Stating application's  main method----------------- ");
    AWSCredentials credential = new ProfileCredentialsProvider("TRFAuditability-Prod-ServiceUser").getCredentials();
    final ClientConfiguration config = new ClientConfiguration();

    AmazonS3Client s3Client = (AmazonS3Client) AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withRegion("us-east-1")
            .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credential)).withForceGlobalBucketAccessEnabled(true)
            .build();

    s3Client.getClientConfiguration().setMaxConnections(100);

    TransferManager tm = new TransferManager(s3Client);
    while (true) {
        FileProcessThreads fp = new FileProcessThreads();
        List<File> records = fp.process(fileLocation);
        while (records.size() <= 0) {
            try {
                _logger.info("No records found willl wait for 10 Seconds");
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);
                records = fp.process(fileLocation);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                _logger.error("InterruptedException: " + e.toString());
            }
        }
        _logger.info("Total no of Audit files = " + records.size());
        ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        int recordsInEachThread = (int) (records.size() / 2);
        _logger.info("No of records in each thread = " + recordsInEachThread);
        UploadObject my1 = new UploadObject(records.subList(0, recordsInEachThread), tm);
        UploadObject my2 = new UploadObject(records.subList(recordsInEachThread, records.size()), tm);

        es.execute(my1);
        es.execute(my2);
        es.shutdown();
        try {
            boolean finshed = es.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
            if (!finshed) {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            _logger.error("InterruptedException: " + e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

}

Last class where i upload files into S3

```
public class UploadObject implements Runnable{
static String bucketName = "a205381-auditxml/S3UPLOADER";
private String fileLocation="C:\\Users\\u6034690\\Desktop\\ONEFILE";
//private String fileLocation="D:\\TRFAudits\\";
//static String bucketName = "a205381-auditxml/S3UPLOADER"; 

private static Logger _logger;

List<File> records;
TransferManager tm;

UploadObject(List<File> list,TransferManager tm){
    this.records = list;
    this.tm=tm;
    _logger = Logger.getLogger(UploadObject.class);
}
public void run(){
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " : ");
        uploadToToS3();
}

public  void uploadToToS3() {

    _logger.info("Number of record to be processed in current thread: : "+records.size());
    MultipleFileUpload xfer = tm.uploadFileList(bucketName, "TEST",new File(fileLocation), records);
    try {
        xfer.waitForCompletion();
        TransferState xfer_state = xfer.getState();
        _logger.info("Upload status -----------------" + xfer_state);

        for (File file : records) {
            try {
                Files.delete(FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(file.getAbsolutePath()));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.exit(1);
                _logger.error("IOException: "+e.toString());
            }
        }

        _logger.info("Successfully completed file cleanse");

    } catch (AmazonServiceException e) {
        _logger.error("AmazonServiceException: "+e.toString());
        System.exit(1);
    } catch (AmazonClientException e) {
        _logger.error("AmazonClientException: "+e.toString());
        System.exit(1);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        _logger.error("InterruptedException: "+e.toString());
        System.exit(1);
    }

    System.out.println("Completed");
    _logger.info("Upload completed");
    _logger.info("Calling Transfer manager shutdown");
    //tm.shutdownNow();

}
```

}

Comment: Did you enable the translate accelerate feature in s3? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/enable-transfer-acceleration.html.. You can also enable using Java API https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/transfer-acceleration-examples.html#transfer-acceleration-examples-java

Comment: @notionquest yes already enabled that ..Also i am pushing from same region.Do you think i have code optimize here

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're tripping the built-in protections for S3 (quoted docs below). I've also listed some similar questions below; some of these advise rearchitecting using SQS to even out and distribute the load on S3.

Aside from introducing more moving pieces, you can reuse your `S3Client` and [TransferManager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/transfer/TransferManager.html). Move them up out of your runnable object and pass them into its constructor. `TransferManager` itself uses multithreading according to the javadoc.

> When possible, TransferManager attempts to use multiple threads to upload multiple parts of a single upload at once. When dealing with large content sizes and high bandwidth, this can have a significant increase on throughput.

You can also increase the [max number of simultaneous connections](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/ClientConfiguration.html#setMaxConnections-int-) that the S3Client uses.

Maybe:

`s3Client.getClientConfiguration().setMaxConnections(75)` or even higher.

[`DEFAULT_MAX_CONNECTIONS` is set to 50](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/constant-values.html#com.amazonaws.ClientConfiguration.DEFAULT_MAX_CONNECTIONS).

Lastly, you could try to upload to different prefixes/folders under the bucket, as noted below to allow scaling for high request rates.

The current AWS [Request Rate and Performance Guidelines](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/request-rate-perf-considerations.html)

> Amazon S3 automatically scales to high request rates. For example, your application can achieve at least 3,500 PUT/POST/DELETE and 5,500 GET requests per second per prefix in a bucket. There are no limits to the number of prefixes in a bucket. It is simple to increase your read or write performance exponentially. For example, if you create 10 prefixes in an Amazon S3 bucket to parallelize reads, you could scale your read performance to 55,000 read requests per second.

The current AWS [S3 Error Best Practices](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ErrorBestPractices.html)

> **Tune Application for Repeated SlowDown errors**
>
> As with any distributed system, S3 has protection mechanisms which detect intentional or unintentional resource over-consumption and react accordingly. SlowDown errors can occur when a high request rate triggers one of these mechanisms. Reducing your request rate will decrease or eliminate errors of this type. Generally speaking, most users will not experience these errors regularly; however, if you would like more information or are experiencing high or unexpected SlowDown errors, please post to our Amazon S3 developer forum https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ or sign up for AWS Premium Support https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/.

Similar questions:

[S3 SlowDown: Please reduce your request rate exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46787072/s3-slowdown-please-reduce-your-request-rate-exception)

[Amazon Web Services S3 Request Limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17307373/amazon-web-services-s3-request-limit)

[AWS Forums - Maximizing Connection Reuse for S3 getObjectMetadata() Calls](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=110998)

Comment: Thanks  Jon for taking sparing your time and reviewing my code ..I made all code changes suggested by you ..I got got to ask two things .1) Do i have close TrasnferMnager connection after upload ? 2.)Is calling main class agagin and agagin in the while is ok ?

Comment: Re: #1 - I don't think it's appropriate to close the `TransferManager` while your program is running. You would be closing resources which could be re-used during successive or concurrent (things would break) uploads. Re: #2 - It sounds like you're asking if using a while loop in a main method is a good way to create a daemon. That's a whole question on it's own ( [How to run a program forever in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12199011/how-to-run-a-program-forever-in-java-is-system-in-read-the-only-way) )

Comment: when i ran my code it is calling threads but without competed the upload it calla the same thread again and again . I have given `xfer.waitForCompletion();` so ideally it should wait for the upload to be completed then it should go for next upload .

Comment: When i ran modified code MultiThreading did not work .Because TransferManager is created once and passed in constructor .When i created inside Runnable files are uploading faster .

Comment: `TransferManager` does indeed appear to only be useful for splitting large files. You may find [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/parallelizing-large-uploads-for-speed-and-reliability/) blog entry valuable in that regard. I would suggest though that removing the `TransferManager` and doing multi-threaded uploads via the client might be more straightforward for you to control.

Comment: I went through the blog you have shared but it does use `TransferManager`..So you are suggesting not to use `TransferManager` ..IN that case do i have to upload file by file ?

Comment: In the case of no 'TransferManager': yes - you are responsible for individual uploads.

Comment: Got it ..But individual upload is very very slow compared to list upload

Answer (score 0):

S3 Transfer Acceleration does not necessarily give faster upload speeds. It is sometime slower than normal upload when using from same region. Amazon S3 Transfer Acceleration uses the AWS edge infrastructure they have around the world to get data on to the aws backbone quicker. When you use Amazon S3 Transfer Acceleration your request is routed to the best AWS edge location based on latency. Transfer Acceleration will then send your uploads back to S3 over the AWS-managed backbone network using optimized network protocols, persistent connections from edge to origin, fully-open send and receive windows, and so forth. As you would already be within the region you wouldn't see any benefit to using this. But, its better to test the speed from https://s3-accelerate-speedtest.s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com/en/accelerate-speed-comparsion.html

Comment: We did this test without TA on as well but the rate of uploading files is same